# logging to a file and stderr with a Python logger

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7

I am trying to add a module to a project that uses the standard Python (2.7) logging libraries. What I want to achieve is the following:

- Anything equal or worse than WARNING goes to wherever the main program (outside of my control) has configured the logging to go (usually stderr)
- Everything else (debug messages mainly) goes to a log file

Please note that the key issue here is that I do not want to modify the global logging settings, since those are controlled by the main app. Otherwise I would use the example in here:

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations

I've tried this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('my_module')
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
fh = logging.FileHandler('my_module.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

but then I only get warning messages in my file.

If I replace the above line with:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

then I get debug messages in both stderr and my file.

Then I tried this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('my_module')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logger.addHandler(console)
fh = logging.FileHandler('my_module.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

But again no luck.

So can I achieve this without having to call basicConfig() or anything else that affects the global logging infrastructure? I only want to modify my own module here if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Anything equal or worse than WARNING goes to wherever the main program (outside of my control) has configured the logging to go
>     (usually stderr)
> - Everything else (debug messages mainly) go to a log file

You can't do it with a single logger without setting WARNING level on ancestor's handlers. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate):

> ```
> Logger.propagate
> ```
>
> If this evaluates to true, logging messages are passed by this logger and by its child loggers to the handlers of higher level
>   (ancestor) loggers. Messages are passed directly to the ancestor
>   loggers’ handlers - neither the level nor filters of the ancestor
>   loggers in question are considered.

---

> what do you suggest a module can do in this situation?

In general other than the setting of WARNING level for the logger and adding `NullHandler()`, library code shouldn't configure logging at all.

If you want an easy way for the main application to provide you with a debug info then define a function that configures DEBUG level logging for your library.

---

> I don't want the library to be DEBUG except for the file, where I would like to see everything.

If you can't control the main program then you shouldn't create debug files as a side-effect  of using your_module unless explicitly asked to do so:

```
import your_module # in the main application

your_module.get_logger().log_to_file(filename) # without this line your module
                                               # shouldn't create debug files
...
your_module.some_function()
```

---

> I am not sure how this logger hierarchy works: the logger I created is a child of the root logger that the app configured?

`''` is a root logger. `'a.b'` is a child of `'a'` logger.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If it is not possible to do so then what do you suggest a module can do in this situation? I don't quite understand your suggestion about a function that configures DEBUG for the library. I don't want the library to be DEBUG except for the file, where I would like to see everything. I am not sure how this logger hierarchy works: the logger I created is a child of the root logger that the app configured?

Comment: @introiboad: I've added answers to questions in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two loggers pointing to the same file. One .ERROR and one .WARNING. Never done this with Python, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. As long as you flush your streams after writes, they should not interfere with one another, unless you are running co-routines, in which case you would need to program in some locks and such. As long as your program runs linearly you shouldn't have any worries.

Comment: That wouldn't achieve what I want it to though. If I set the logger level to DEBUG everything goes to stderr, and if I set it to WARNING, none of the debug info goes to the file, that is my problem here.